# VBA Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when trying to save worksheet as pdf

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to create an invoice template for sponsors of our student council.
However when I press the button that runs the macro I get the Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim invno As Long
Dim firmname As String
Dim semester As String
Dim amt As Currency
Dim dt_issue As Date
Dim term As Byte
Dim nextrec As Range
Dim path As String
Dim fname As String

Sub SaveAspdf()
    path = "/Users/zediwan/Documents/[03] University/[09] Student Council Finances/[03] Invoices/"
    invno = Range("C3")
    firmname = Range("B10")
    semester = Range("C4")
    fname = invno & "-" & firmname & "-" & semester
    MsgBox "File path: " & path & fname
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, FileName:=path & fname
    
    Set nextrec = Sheet3.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    nextrec = invno
    nextrec.Offset(0, 1) = firmname
    nextrec.Offset(0, 2) = amt
    nextrec.Offset(0, 3) = dt_issue
    nextrec.Offset(0, 4) = dt_issue + term
    
    Sheet3.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=nextrec.Offset(0, 6), Address:=path & fname & ".pdf"
End Sub
```

Comment: What does that MsgBox display?

Comment: Please install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and take a look at the static code inspections it produces.

Comment: FunThomas don't like my help, so I hope someone else can help, like FunThomas..

Comment: No comment FunThomas? Ok, I suspect that the path is the issue. When I change the path, the code down to the row `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` works for me. Try to comment out the last part to narrow it down where the issue lies.

Comment: @Loveb don't understand why I should comment. I don't know the reason why it fails, and I never worked on a Mac, so what do you expect me to write?

Comment: FunThomas, If you have opinion about others code, then you shoud come up with a better code yourself, instead of back talking others code.

Comment: You mean I may point to issues in an answer only if I answer myself? Strange thought. Btw: I neither asked you to delete your answer nor did I downvote it. But I want to end this topic now.